# Android Studio 0.5.3 - Why doesn't "Make Project" run build any more?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

"Make Project" in Android Studio doesn't build an apk file for me since I upgraded to 0.5.3. Does anyone know how I can make it do so?

I have updated buildToolsVersion to 19.0.3, which is the latest version.

(Every time Android Studio updates it creates another problem like this, I'm sorry but I'm not an expert on build systems, I scarcely even have any idea what kind of voodoo is involved in building a project).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to now run an assemble gradle task to make the apk.  Here is a post on Google+ in "Android Developer Tools" community on the subject (By Alex Ruiz).

"Build > Make" behavior changes.
In the next version of Android Studio (0.5.3,) we have changed the behavior of the "Build > "Make" menus. Instead of invoking "assemble" Gradle tasks, now they only compile Java code (generating R.java if necessary,) similar to Eclipse ADT's behavior. This change will speed up development workflows (pre-dex, dex, packaging, etc. will be executed only when running/debugging an app or when exporting an APK.)
As a side effect the menu "Build > Compile" has been removed, since it is now redundant.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. How would you recommend running an assemble gradle task in a convenient way from the IDE (without having to use the command line)? I have resorted to adding gradlew as an external tool and adding a toolbar button for it, but I would be interested in knowing the method recommended by the omniscient Google engineers. I wonder why couldn't they have put the change to the button behaviour in the release announcement? There is no mention of it: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio053released. Do I need to look elsewhere for release notes? Thanks again for answering.

Comment: I know you can use "Gradle-aware Make" as a task to be run before launch, which will build the APK, but I don't want the project to Make every time I run it, I'd rather make it and run it separately as necessary. I know, I'm weird.

Comment: I run IntelliJ Ultimate, so there may be differences between that and Android Studio.  But for me, I never have had the need to manually use "make".  I set up a run configuration to deploy my app to my phone/emulator.  Then when I want to run it I just hit play (or shift F10).  Unless I'm needing to run the app I haven't had a need to manually make it.  When I want to release I run the assembleRelease gradle task from the gradle sidebar plugin window.

Answer (score 5):

The "Make" button in Android Studio now runs the gradle android plugin task "compileDebugJava". In order to build the APK file, it needs to run the task "assembleDebug". I'm not sure what the rationale was for changing the behaviour of the button, or how to change it back. The only easy way (i.e. not using the command line) to get the assembleDebug task to run is to have a run configuration which runs a "Gradle-aware Make" before launch. The "gradle-aware Make" is simply the assembleDebug task.

I preferred the old behaviour, but of course, Google knows best.

Edit: I know nobody cares, but I worked around this by adding gradlew to Android Studio as an external tool, with the command line option "assembleDebug" and then adding a custom button to the toolbar to run this external tool. I now use this button instead of the Make Project button as it does what I would like to do (build an APK).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to build the APK file:

1. Open the Gradle Tool window. To find that window, use Help->Find Action, type "Gradle" and select "Gradle" in the "Tool Windows" category;
2. Double-click "assembleDebug" to build the APK.
   Or better: right-click "assembleDebug" and choose "Create...", so that this task will be saved for future usage in the configurations menu that appear on the main toolbar.