# Android studio 0.5.3 is not generating AAR file for a library project

Tags: gradle, aar

since the update to 5.3 android studio is not generating the ".aar" file nor the "build/libs" folder,

i have tried to create a new library project , same issue

anyway to fix this issue? maybe try to force the output file name?

Comment: i was able to make the .aar file using the command gradlew aR , but it doesnt work using the gui

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio 0.5.3 - Why doesn't "Make Project" run build any more?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743043/android-studio-0-5-3-why-doesnt-make-project-run-build-any-more)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the task you want and click "Run".

[image: Right click the task you want and click "Run".]